# Python Pandas - Append data to specific row and column

Tags: python, pandas

after searching, I don't think this is a duplicate, but if it is please let me know.

I currently have a data frame with a number of rows and variables. I would like to create a separate data frame of a single row which is the mean of each variable. I'm doing this so that I can easily plot it in a graph. I'm not sure why my syntax doesn't work.

This is for one specific variable. If I can get this to work, then I can expand it to all the columns with a loop.

```
avg = pd.DataFrame(columns=original.columns.values)
avg['max_yds'].loc[0] = original['max_yds'].mean(axis=0)
```

In my mind, the first line creates a data frame called 'avg' which is empty and has all the columns from original. This seems to work as expected. For the second line, I expect it to set the first row of the variable 'max_yds' in 'avg' and set it to the mean of the variable of 'max_yds' from original. Instead, I get: `Empty DataFrame`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
avg.set_value(0, 'max_yds', original['max_yds'].mean(axis=0))
```

If you want to compute mean for all columns, why not use

```
avg = avg.append(original.mean(axis=0), ignore_index=True)
```

**Edit:**

The problem of your original solution is that you are using a kind of "[chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)", which is bad.

You add value to the Series in each column, but the index of the DataFrame is still empty.

Actually, if you add

```
avg['max_yds'] = avg['max_yds']
```

after

```
avg['max_yds'].loc[0] = original['max_yds'].mean(axis=0)
```

, your code will work as well.

Or you can specify the index at the beginning, which also can fix your problem.

```
avg = pd.DataFrame(columns=original.columns.values, index=[0])
```

However, it is not recommended to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be using the second method.

Though, I still don't understand why my syntax doesn't work?

(Upvoted - doesn't show publicly yet!)

Comment: Updated some discussion on your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may use loc too :

```
avg.loc[0, 'max_yds'] = original.loc[:, 'max_yds'].mean()
```

Alternatively, you can easily retrieve statistics using `pandas.DataFrame.describe` method.

So if you want a serie with the mean for all column :

`avg = original.describe().loc['mean']`

If you need the expected output dataframe:

`avg = pd.DataFrame(index = [0], original.describe().loc['mean']).transpose()`

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I completely understand why I can pass two arguments to loc, and I'll need to think through using 'describe'. 

(Upvoted - doesn't show publicly yet!)